# Closing the lid no longer suspends the laptop

Tags: suspend

After recent kernel (3.19.0-28-generic) and upgrades from daily repos, I realised that closing the lid no longer suspends the laptop.

Running a state checker shows the laptop knows the lid is closing:

```
while true; do cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state ; sleep 3; done
state:      open
state:      open
state:      closed
state:      open
state:      open
state:      closed
state:      open
state:      open
```

I also made a lid.sh file in /etc/acpi/local, which i think worked once only!

```
#!/bin/bash
 if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state
 then
     /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
 fi
```

This feature used to work fine until recently. Toshiba Portege R830

Answer (score 1):

It could be a kernel issue. When Freya 0.3.1 was released, I did a fresh install, and I had the issue you describe. Going back to kernel 3.16.0-34-generic fixed the problem. I've noticed this issue with other Linux distributions that use versions higher than 3.16. This could be an issue with newer kernel versions, or just a quirk with my particular laptop.